# Intellij Idea How to add interface implementation to classes?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, code-completion, automated-refactoring

For example I have many classes than implement my interface. After adding new method definition in the interface, how can I fast-add blank interface implementations for all that classes?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the new method in the interface, **Implement method**:

[image]

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the list of implementation classes will be shown, select the desired classes using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+arrow keys or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all of them, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to confirm the choice. Stub implementations will be added to all the selected classes.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best you can do comes from their [code generation tutorial](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_generation.html), particularly by using

> Ctrl+O

in an implementing class.  Otherwise I'm not aware of a way to generate an entire class.

Comment: That's the question. I know that I can go through all classed and insert implementation. But I want ability to implement methods for all classes from interface.

Comment: @Jack, right.  I believe that is not possible, and this is the closest alternative.

Answer (score 5):

You can generate an implementation of an interface by **moving the caret to the name of the interface** and pressing <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> (on Mac) or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (on PC), then hovering over `Implement interface` and pressing <kbd>return</kbd>/<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image: Implement interface]
**Please note that my caret can't be seen but it's between the `h` and `a` of `Shape`**

IntelliJ will then prompt you for a class name and which methods to include in the implementation, then generate a class, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In IntellyJ IDEA 12 you can use Push Members Down dialog:

```
Refactor -> Pull Members Down...
```

Then select methods you want to push to subclasses and click "Refactor":
http://clip2net.com/s/i6DK41

Note that it doesn't generate the stub method by base class - it just moves it as is.
So you'll need to implement the stub by yourself in the parent (root) class, e.g.:

```
public boolean getRequiredDatabaseNameWhenPartitioned() {
  return true;
}
```

then use "Push members down", refactor, and finally make the method of the parent class abstract manually