# How to add abstract method for a new implemented method in subclass to interface or abstract class in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

If a class is implementing a certain interface or extending a class with abstract methods, it has to implement the methods of such interface or class. IntelliJ IDEA creates the implemented methods, with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd>. 
How about vice versa ?

For example I have a class that implements my interface.

After **adding** a new method definition in the class, how can I fast-add  an abstract method in the interface?

Is there any short key for it?

Comment: Not familiar with intellij, but I suppose the IDE options listing shortcuts would be a good place to try? Did you search that before posting?

Comment: yes I searched it, but didn't found a short key for it. but putting Override annotation will bring the intellij suggestions and add it to interface as @ghostcat said

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intellij Idea How to add interface implementation to classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401347/intellij-idea-how-to-add-interface-implementation-to-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way of doing this is to add the `@Override` annotation to the new method you just added, which will cause a compilation error (since this method doesn't override anything). Then, place you carret on the annotation and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. IntelliJ will open a context menu, where one of the options is "Pull method 'methodName' to 'InterfaceName'" - choose it to get your method declared in the interface/abstract class you're extending.

Answer (score 1):

A potential workaround: simply put @Override on that method in your class.

That will lead to a compile error; and I am sure that IntelliJ would then offer you to add that method to your interface. (that is what I would do in eclipse).